# Visual Studio 2022, it automatically adds NuGet Package for Microsoft.Data.SQLClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever we add a new DataSet and Table Adapter in ASP.NET Web Site (Framework 4.7.2) in Visual Studio 2022, it automatically adds NuGet Package for Microsoft.Data.SQLClient. It was not happening in the version 17.4.3 and previous versions of VS2022. After updating to the latest version of VS 2022 probably from 17.5.x the issue started. We want to stick to System.Data.SQLClient and do not want this automatic addition of Microsoft.Data.SQLClient which results in inclusion of few hundreds of files under packages. We are forced to use VS2019 for just adding datasets to our ASP.NET Web Site.

What does this mean for System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Microsoft has decided to stop the development of `System.Data.SqlClient` and rather focus on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. So this means `System.Data.SqlClient` won't receive any updates anymore, however it will still work for existing apps. Any new features will be integrated into `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

It seems like Visual Studio 2022 now uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` as default when you add a `Table Adapter` or a `DataSet`.

Comment: Hello, do you have a reason to use System.Data.SqlClient? Microsoft.Data.SQLClient has better support in .net. You can refer to [Introducing the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/)